# Flutter & Firestore - problem about "startAfter" pagination

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am able to use "startAfter" and "limit" to do pagination but it have bug.

For example, in Firestore DB I have 7 records:

```
{"title": "item1", "create_datetime": "2018-11-11 11:11:11"}
{"title": "item2", "create_datetime": "2018-11-11 11:11:11"}
{"title": "item3", "create_datetime": "2018-11-11 11:11:11"}
{"title": "item4", "create_datetime": "2018-11-11 11:11:11"}
{"title": "item5", "create_datetime": "2018-11-11 11:11:11"}
{"title": "item6", "create_datetime": "2018-11-11 11:11:11"}
{"title": "item7", "create_datetime": "2018-12-22 22:22:22"}
```

When the page size is 5, first page is ok because I used:

```
.orderBy('create_datetime').limit(5)
```

It gives me item 1-5.

When it load second page, I used:

```
.orderBy('create_datetime').startAfter(['2018-11-11 11:11:11']).limit(5)
```

The problem is that the second page result had item7 only, item6 was disappeared.
"startAt" have the same problem too.

I really hope it has "offset" function. Does anyone have solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your query will always return 'item7' because you always starting after `2018-11-11 11:11:11` so it will ignore all the other items and go to the last `2018-11-11 11:11:11` and skip from there. You need to get the last item returned and keep a reference to it, then on your startAfter use the document reference to start after. Usually, flutter's startAfter requires a list to keep a reference to it.

Look at [Firebase query cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)

Comment: Passing a document reference is not yet supported in Flutter package.

Answer (score 0):

Currently flutter don't support `startAfter(lastDocFetched)` or `startAt(anyDoc)`.
This is required as you said it starts with the string matching values, not at a particular document.